Understanding the built-in compile function in Python
I am learning about compile() and the dis module. If I have all my code in the same module, I can see how every line in compiled. I am now trying to understand how code from multiple modules is compiled.
For this, I have the following two files.
#test.py
import sys
from temp import doubler

def tripler(n: int) -> int:
    f = 3 * n
        
    return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 4
    t = tripler(n)
    s = doubler(t)
    print(s)

#temp.py
def doubler(x):
    y = 2 * x
    return y

I then run compile() for the text from test.py and the output of dis.dis() is as follows
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (sys)
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (sys)

  2          10 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (('doubler',))
             14 IMPORT_NAME              1 (temp)
             16 IMPORT_FROM              2 (doubler)
             18 STORE_NAME               2 (doubler)
             20 POP_TOP

  4          22 LOAD_CONST               3 ('n')
             24 LOAD_NAME                3 (int)
             26 LOAD_CONST               4 ('return')
             28 LOAD_NAME                3 (int)
             30 BUILD_TUPLE              4
             32 LOAD_CONST               5 (<code object tripler at 0x00000255AB98F910, file "test.py", line 4>)
             34 MAKE_FUNCTION            4 (annotations)
             36 STORE_NAME               4 (tripler)

  9          38 LOAD_NAME                5 (__name__)
             40 LOAD_CONST               6 ('__main__')
             42 COMPARE_OP              40 (==)
             46 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       69 (to 186)

 10          48 PUSH_NULL
             50 LOAD_NAME                6 (len)
             52 LOAD_NAME                0 (sys)
             54 LOAD_ATTR               14 (argv)
             74 CALL                     1
             82 LOAD_CONST               7 (1)
             84 COMPARE_OP              68 (>)
             88 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       21 (to 132)
             90 PUSH_NULL
             92 LOAD_NAME                3 (int)
             94 LOAD_NAME                0 (sys)
             96 LOAD_ATTR               14 (argv)
            116 LOAD_CONST               7 (1)
            118 BINARY_SUBSCR
            122 CALL                     1
            130 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 134)
        >>  132 LOAD_CONST               8 (10)
        >>  134 STORE_NAME               8 (n)

 11         136 PUSH_NULL
            138 LOAD_NAME                4 (tripler)
            140 LOAD_NAME                8 (n)
            142 CALL                     1
            150 STORE_NAME               9 (t)

 12         152 PUSH_NULL
            154 LOAD_NAME                2 (doubler)
            156 LOAD_NAME                9 (t)
            158 CALL                     1
            166 STORE_NAME              10 (s)

 13         168 PUSH_NULL
            170 LOAD_NAME               11 (print)
            172 LOAD_NAME               10 (s)
            174 CALL                     1
            182 POP_TOP
            184 RETURN_CONST             1 (None)

  9     >>  186 RETURN_CONST             1 (None)

Disassembly of <code object tripler at 0x00000255AB98F910, file "test.py", line 4>:
  4           0 RESUME                   0

  5           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 BINARY_OP                5 (*)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (f)

  7          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

I can see that the symbol doubler is imported from temp. I cannot see the codeobject for it though. I also don't understand at which stage it is even compiled. The code object executes fine. Can someone explain what happens with the module temp?

Compilation (creation of the relevant .pyc file) occurs during import

Can I see the bytecode anywhere when I use the compile() function?

Put dis.dis(doubler) after the import line.

Ok, I can see the implementation for doubler by doing that. I also have a suspicion that the temp module is first compiled when the dis.dis() call happens. Apparently compile() just generates the calls to these external functions without compiling them as well. I could verify this by introducing a deliberate mistake in the function in the external module and noticing that compile() processed the main module without any errors. It is only after calling exec() that the errors are flagged.
